# Warning: Illegal string offset - PHP 5.4

Tags: php, string, warnings, offset

I get error Warning: Illegal string offset 'rent' in

```
<?php
    $rentdata = get_option("rent_data", true);
    if ($rentdata["rent"] == 1 || $rentdata["rent"] == true) {
        echo $rentdata["template"];
    }
    $fontsStyls = get_option("google_font_settings", true);
?>
```

Comment: `print_R($rentdata);` and then you know why you get an error!

Comment: if index `rent` doesn't exist, then it pretty much screws up that condition.

Comment: `$rentdata` is a string not an array

Comment: `if( isset($rentdata["rent"]) && (the rest) )`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that in your $rentdata is no associative element called "rent".

try

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rentdata);
echo "</pre>";
```

to inspect your array.

Comment: And where is the answer? This is only a comment

Comment: I can't write comments to a question. only in my own answers or questions. So I write a solution for Shawn that he can try this out so he find the solution for his problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the key `rent` can not be found in the array. You should add an extra check to your `if` to see if the `rent` key exists in your array.

```
<?php
    $rentdata = get_option("rent_data", true);
    if(isset($rentdata["rent"]) && ($rentdata["rent"] == 1 || $rentdata["rent"] == true)) {
        echo $rentdata["template"];
    }
    $fontsStyls = get_option("google_font_settings", true);
?>
```